# Get an extra comma ',' while using concat

Tags: mysql

I have wrote a stored proc in `sqlyog`. It is quite long and performing all the desired functionality except for the *concat* statement so I will only list that particular query.

```
UPDATE recipes_new 
SET co_auths = CONCAT(co_auths,',',c1id) 
WHERE id = name_in;
```

I basically want a separation in the two fields and this statement is placed in a cursor so it is iterative. `co_auths` is null at the moment so I get the result as *,1,2,3* where as I want it to be *1,2,3*. Any guesses what can the most appropriate solution be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using an [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
UPDATE recipes_new 
SET co_auths = IF(co_auths IS NULL, c1id, CONCAT(co_auths, ',', c1id))
WHERE id = name_in;
```

If the value of `co_auths` is an empty string instead of `NULL`:

```
UPDATE recipes_new 
SET co_auths = IF(LENGTH(co_auths), CONCAT(co_auths, ',', c1id), c1id)
WHERE id = name_in;
```

Comment: UPDATE recipes_new SET co_auths= (IF(co_auths IS NULL, c1id, CONCAT(co_auths, ',', c1id))WHERE id=name_in);  Am I right because im getting an error

Comment: @Shahzaib You said the value of `co_auths` was null ... is it an empty string instead?

Comment: Oh sorry I confused empty and Null. Yes its empty

Comment: @Shahzaib the reason I'm asking is because you unaccepted this answer.

Comment: Actually yours and @sgeddes both worked. So I ticked both, now I get it only one can be ticked at a time so since I found u to be much more helpful and knowledgeable I have again ticked accepted ur answer. Thanks again

Comment: I posted another question today, can you please see that and tell me if you could help me in solving that

Comment: @Shahzaib yes you can only accept one, but if other answers were useful to you, you should up vote them, since you have 20 rep now.

Comment: please see my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036056/repetition-of-last-number-on-update-in-a-stored-procedure

Comment: @Shahzaib I've up voted that question, but I don't know the exact answer because I don't do PLSQL much

Comment: can you please tell me how to get the total number of records that are being returned on execution of a cursor?

Comment: @Shahzaib Wish I could tell you, but I don't do stored procedures ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This should work using `CASE` to check if it's NULL:

```
CONCAT(
    CASE 
        WHEN IFNULL(co_auths,'') = ''
        THEN '' 
        ELSE CONCAT(co_auths, ',') 
    END, c1id)
```

Comment: The problem still remains there

Comment: @Shahzaib -- Updated answer to check for blank and null -- best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL returning an empty field: CONCAT(nonEmpty1,empty2,nonEmpty3) = NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981214/mysql-returning-an-empty-field-concatnonempty1-empty2-nonempty3-null)
CONCAT_WS is what you are looking for

```
UPDATE recipes_new SET co_auths = CONCAT_WS(co_auths,',',c1id) WHERE id = name_in;
```

Comment: I have tried this already it displays only the fist number i.e out of 1,2,3 only 1

Comment: Use NULLIF to also skip empty fields as well as nulls https://stackoverflow.com/a/3924726/74585