# MySQL Using result from one query in another

Tags: mariadb

When a user buys a license for my product I'm trying to add the number of days remaining (if he has any) to the new 30-day period.

```
SELECT
    SUM(DATEDIFF(access_expires, CURDATE())) + 30 as access_remaining
FROM wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions
WHERE
    user_email = 'user@mail.com' AND
    product_id = 8 AND access_expires IS NOT NULL;

UPDATE wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions
SET
    access_expires = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), access_remaining)
WHERE
    user_email = 'user@mail.com' AND
    product_id = 8 AND
    access_expires IS NULL
```

It seems like I can't use access_remaining from my previous query in my second query. Please help, if possible without using join. Using mariadb if it means anything.

Comment: You can't reuse an alias like that.  I think the closest thing to what you have in mind would be an updatable CTE, which however MySQL does not support.

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same thing as `SET access_expires = DATE_ADD(access_expires,INTERVAL 30 DAY)`?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have imposed odd restrictions on this problem. Are you using strictly `/usr/bin/mysql`, and cannot use e.g. python or java? Can you assign to a temp variable with `:=` ? Why no JOIN?

Consider using UPDATE with correlated sub-query, as in [MySQL/SQL: Update with correlated subquery from the updated table itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839938/update-with-correlated-subquery#844637) .

You chose a perfectly sensible way to model the bookkeeping, by maintaining a calendar expiry date. But consider modeling in a different way: you might store (begin, end) dates for which a customer is paid up. You might find it makes some queries easier to phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the use of a "user variable" `@ar`:

```
SELECT
    @ar := SUM(DATEDIFF(access_expires, CURDATE())) + 30 as access_remaining
FROM wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions
WHERE
    user_email = 'user@mail.com' AND
    product_id = 8 AND access_expires IS NOT NULL;

UPDATE wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions
SET
    access_expires = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), @ar)
WHERE
    user_email = 'user@mail.com' AND
    product_id = 8 AND
    access_expires IS NULL
```

I suggest that `SUM` does not make sense in this context.

Wouldn't it be simpler to just do this?

```
UPDATE wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions
SET
    access_expires = GREATEST(access_expires, CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 30 DAY
WHERE
    user_email = 'user@mail.com' AND
    product_id = 8 AND
    access_expires IS NULL
```