# MySQL Update Condtional for Three columns Between Two DBs

Tags: mysql, sql-update, database-migration

Having difficulty writing a statement that will allow me to:
UPDATE column C in DB1.table1 with data from column B in DB2.table2 IF column B IS NOT null AND column A FROM DB1.table1 = column A FROM DB2.table2 (matching IDs)

Can't tell if I need to use a CASE statement or IF. Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: You don't need in IF/CASE. You must write according ON clause expression in JOIN/WHERE.

Comment: Can you give or refer me to an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839938/mysql-sql-update-with-correlated-subquery-from-the-updated-table-itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE DB1.table1                                 
  JOIN DB2.table2 ON DB2.table2.B IS NOT NULL     -- IF column B IS NOT null
                 AND DB1.table1.A = DB2.table2.A  -- AND column A FROM DB1.table1 
                                                  -- = column A FROM DB2.table2 (matching IDs)
SET DB1.table1.C = DB2.table2.B                   -- UPDATE column C in DB1.table1 
                                                  -- with data from column B in DB2.table2
```